# Host Windows 10, Guest Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop LTS: copy file in shared folder from command line but can't through file manager gui

Tags: virtualbox, shared-folders

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop running as a guest OS in VirtualBox 6.1, which is running on the host Windows 10 system.

I have shared a folder from the Windows host which should be accessible to the Ubuntu. I can see it in Files (file manager GUI)  and in `/media/sf_SharedFolder` where it is owned by the group `vboxsf`, and my logged-in user has been added to this group. The problem is that I  can copy & paste through the terminal (CLI) but can't through Files (the Ubuntu file manager GUI). How can this be resolved? i use drag&drop and copy&paste through mouse but failed everytime. there is no error on screen.

Comment: What happens when you try to use the GUI? Any errors?

Comment: @terdon thanks for replying. no, its not showing error, i use drag&drop and copy&paste through mouse but failed everytime. there is no error on screen.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add that. Also, try launching the GUI file manager from a terminal (open a terminal and run `nautilus`). Then, try copy/pasting and tell us if any errors are printed in the terminal. Finally, please [edit] your question and explain exactly how you are "copy pasting". Do you right click, select copy, then select paste? Do you drag and drop? Do you use keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: hi, sorry for delay but yesterday i saw it in last moments here at work, just modified my post as instructed and leave. today started my Ubuntu VM and in terminal run  nautilus ... nothing works, all things same (also tried keyboard shotcuts Ctrl-C and Ctrl-V) and in terminal it is showing this message:
" Nautilus-Share-Message: 10:23:38.152: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: Failed to execute child process “net” (No such file or directory) "